# ack - search for multiple patterns (logical AND)

Tags: regex, perl, ack

How to search file with the `ack` to find lines containing **ALL**  (nor any) of defined patterns?

the *ANY (OR)* is easy, like:

```
ack 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3'
```

but how to write the **AND (ALL)** ? e.g. how to write the following:

```
if( $line =~ /pattern1/ && $line =~ /pattern2/ && $line =~ /pattern3/ ) {
    say $line
}
```

using `ack`?

Or more precisely, is possible create an regex with `logical and`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 /foo/s && /bar/s && /baz/s
```

can be written as

```
 /^(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)(?=.*?baz)/s
```

We don't actually need a look ahead for the last one.

```
 /^(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar).*?baz/s
```

And since we don't care which instance of the pattern is matched if there are more than one, we can simplify that to

```
 /^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar).*baz/s
```

Comment: Thanks! Also: Is there _really_ no easier option?

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution is to apply progressive filtering via chained calls to `ack`:

```
$ ack pattern1 | ack pattern2 | ack pattern3 | ...
```

Comment: yes ;) this is possible with the `grep` too. isn't possible in one ack run? - e.g. perl-regexes doesn't knows something as `AND`?

Comment: @cajwine: Regular expressions do patterns, not logic. To be a bit pedantic: inside a regex the `|` means "alternation," not "or." There's no meta-character for an "and" because that's the implicit default. e.g. the pattern `ab` requires matching the character "a" and the character "b" (in that order, and adjacent to each other). Matching multiple patterns requires either multiple matches (as in amphetamachine's answer) or merging the patterns into a single one (as in ikegami's answer).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar use case where I wanted to find files that contained multiple patterns but (possibly) on different lines.

`ack -l 'pattern1' | ack -xl 'pattern2'`

This allowed me to find files that were using 2 libraries together.